# rsyslog doesnt send any information

Tags: linux, syslog, rsyslog

**Good day, everyone!**

I'm trying to send log files from one Red Hat based server to another Graylog server by using rsyslog.
So I cant do it, cause rsyslog doesn't send anything.
I would really appreciate if someone helps!

**Graylog recieves messages by:**

```
echo "Hello Graylog, let's be friends." | nc -w 1 -u "my-graylog-ip" 13101
```

**I had configured rsyslog.config:**

```
# rsyslog configuration file

# For more information see /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-*/rsyslog_conf.html
# If you experience problems, see http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/troubleshoot.html

#### MODULES ####

# The imjournal module bellow is now used as a message source instead of imuxsock.
$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imjournal # provides access to the systemd journal
#$ModLoad imklog # reads kernel messages (the same are read from journald)
#$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# Provides UDP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imudp
#$UDPServerRun 514

# Provides TCP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imtcp
#$InputTCPServerRun 514


#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####

# Where to place auxiliary files
$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog

# Use default timestamp format
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# File syncing capability is disabled by default. This feature is usually not required,
# not useful and an extreme performance hit
#$ActionFileEnableSync on

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf

# Turn off message reception via local log socket;
# local messages are retrieved through imjournal now.
$OmitLocalLogging on

# File to store the position in the journal
$IMJournalStateFile imjournal.state


#### RULES ####

# Log all kernel messages to the console.
# Logging much else clutters up the screen.
#kern.*                                                 /dev/console

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog


# Log cron stuff
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

# Everybody gets emergency messages
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*

# Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log


# ### begin forwarding rule ###
# The statement between the begin ... end define a SINGLE forwarding
# rule. They belong together, do NOT split them. If you create multiple
# forwarding rules, duplicate the whole block!
# Remote Logging (we use TCP for reliable delivery)
#
# An on-disk queue is created for this action. If the remote host is
# down, messages are spooled to disk and sent when it is up again.
#$ActionQueueFileName fwdRule1 # unique name prefix for spool files
#$ActionQueueMaxDiskSpace 1g   # 1gb space limit (use as much as possible)
#$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save messages to disk on shutdown
#$ActionQueueType LinkedList   # run asynchronously
#$ActionResumeRetryCount -1    # infinite retries if host is down
# remote host is: name/ip:port, e.g. 192.168.0.1:514, port optional
*.* @http://"my-graylog-ip":13101
# ### end of the forwarding rule ###
```

**then restarted rsyslog**

```
systemctl restart rsyslog
```

**in /etc/rsyslog.d/ located grid.conf:**

```
# File 1 
$ModLoad imfile 
$InputFileName /home/ucp/current-envelope/log/envelope.log 
$InputFileTag def-grid101-envelope
$InputFileFacility local0
$InputRunFileMonitor
# File 2 
ModLoad imfile 
$InptFileName /home/ucp/current-envelope/log/envelope-err.log 
$InputFileTag def-grid101-envelope
$InputFileFacility local0 
$InputRunFileMonitor
# File 3 
$ModLoad imfile 
$InputFileName /home/ucp/current-envelope/log/performance.log 
$InputFileTag def-grid101-envelope
$InputFileFacility local0 
$InputRunFileMonitor
```

**journalctl -b | grep rsyslog shows next messages:**

```
Mar 23 10:24:01 grid101 kernel: type=1130 audit(1490253841.179:135915): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=rsyslog comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'

Mar 23 10:45:02 grid101 kernel: type=1131 audit(1490255102.506:135925): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=rsyslog comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'

Mar 23 10:45:02 grid101 kernel: type=1130 audit(1490255102.512:135926): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=rsyslog comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
```

Comment: What Input your Graylog server is using? AFAIK Graylog just works with syslog UDP. Also, I do not think this is right: `*.* @http://"my-graylog-ip":13101`

Comment: I tried a TCP input and UDP in Graylog. and it was `*.* @http://"my-graylog-ip":13101` for UDP and `*.* @@http://"my-graylog-ip":13101` for TCP.
And I think you understand that "my-graylog-ip" is hidden ip) here is smth like this: 11.22.33.44

Answer (score 0):

The `IP:port` configuration is not right. It must be changed to something like this for TCP:

`*.* @@my-graylog-ip:13101`

I wonder why your Graylog server is using the `13101` TCP port. I guess, it is behind a NAT or something like that. I also wonder why you want to use the `http://` thing in your configuration.